# Query on yang deviation

Tags: debugging, deviation, yang

I am new to yang deviations. I wrote a deviation like below but I am not sure if the deviation is effective. Is it possible to print a text(value of xpath) in must statement for debugging purposes? Please help.

```
  deviation "/ns:direction" {

    description "Deviation to restrict if the direction is left.";
     deviate add
     {
      must "(<function to print current()>) " {
        error-message "Direction is not left.";
        description "Direction is not left." ;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to check whether your deviation works would be to feed your module set to a YANG schema aware validator and simply validate an instance document which ensures that your expression evaluates in a desired way. If you tailor the document so that your particular constraint fails, you'd expect the "Direction is not left." error message during validation of said document. I guess you could call that a YANG instance document test case for your YANG schema.

```
module b {
  yang-version 1.1;
  namespace "b:uri";
  prefix b;

  container top {
    leaf direction {
        type enumeration {
            enum left;
            enum right;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```
module c {
  yang-version 1.1;
  namespace "c:uri";
  prefix "c";

  import b {
      prefix b;
  }

  deviation "/b:top/b:direction" {
    deviate add {
      must ". = 'left'" {
        error-message "Direction is not left.";
        description "Direction is not left." ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <b:top xmlns:b="b:uri">
    <b:direction>right</b:direction>
  </b:top>
</config>
```

```
Error at (4:5): failed assert at "/nc:config/b:top/b:direction": Direction is not left.
```

Must statements are assertions about instantiated data nodes so the only way to "debug" those is to throw them against an instance document, configuration + operational state of a device, datastore contents, etc.

It should not matter if the actual constraint is introduced in the original module or later via a deviation. Deviations are just quick and dirty patches of an existing model. You won't find any in modules published by the IETF. You usually resort to them if certain hardware cannot support the requirements of a published model (hard resource limits) or if you implement a big model in several stages, tagging some things as "not-supported" (yet). There are several caveats to them; the order in which they are applied matters for example, you should avoid deviating the same object in several places, you should only define them in specialized modules that only contain deviations (deviation modules), you should consider them to be temporary, etc.